# How to run command in cmd on windows10 by clicking on folder?

Tags: windows-10, command-line

can run command on cmd by clicking on empty folder with custom icon.

for example when click  that folder run this command:  shutdown /s and make system shut down.
something like this  with this icon:

[image]

Comment: why a folder? it would be easy to write a batch script, and point a shortcut to it with a custom icon

Comment: @FrankThomas 
Thanks for your suggestion I m going to try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use bath script.
The steps are:
1 open notepad then copy this :
********@ECHO OFF
shutdown /s /f /t 0
PAUSE********
to shut down the system then you should prese on save as  and change  .txt to .bat
when you do that you have a batch script file then when you double click on that .bat file that command run on cmd and your pc get  shut down.
**for more details** and know how restart pc just by opening bath script file just like shut down **you can read this**  [enter link description here](https://tunecomp.net/shutdown-the-computer-using-cmd-or-a-bat-file/)

[image]

and for changing icon just create shortcut from your bath script file right click on your shortcut go shortcut tab select change icon

[image]